# usage of "as" and "nevertheless"

Tags: meaning

I'm not good at English, and I want to translate a following treatise about Mammography to my mother tongue.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3625776/
And I don' t understand the below sentence (in italics), especially the usage of "as" and "nevertheless". Please paraphrase for me?

> However, our study had several limits. First, we used the breast phantom for a dosimetry evaluation. The phantoms used for this evaluation had a uniform background with a noise characteristic that is not a representative of the anatomical background encountered in clinical mammography studies. Yet, the phantom study is widely used to compare different imaging systems and image acquisition setups due to its ease and reproducibility [12,16-18]. It seemed therefore reasonable to use standard phantoms to obtain an estimate of a possible dose reduction factor. *However it is not as reliable in evaluating the radiation risk as is the patient method, nevertheless employing a phantom with a more anatomically realistic background.*

Note: 1. "it" probably indicates "to use standard phantoms" in the previous sentence.
2. "background" probably means "background noise" in this context.

Comment: Note that this is not written by a native speaker of English: there are several errors of idiom.

Comment: As I understand it: 1. The patient method is more reliable than the use of standard phantoms (comparing the two in evaluating the radiation risk). 2. nevertheless = in spite of -> In spite of employing a phantom with a more anatomically realistic background, when evaluating the radiation risk the phantom method   was not **as reliable as** the patient method. (I don't know if the *phantom method exists, I used that to simplify 'use of standard phantoms' to make the sentence less bulky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However it is not as reliable in evaluating the radiation risk as is
>   the patient method, nevertheless employing a phantom with a more
>   anatomically realistic background.

X is not *as reliable* in doing something *as* is Y = Y is more reliable than X in doing something

X is (not) as {adjective} as Y in doing Z

as reliable as = equally reliable

not as reliable as = less reliable than

"It" [the use of standard phantoms] is less reliable than the "patient method" in evaluating the radiation risk.  The patient method is superior, in this regard, to the use of standard phantoms.

The word *nevertheless* is somewhat unclear here, as are the comparands.  Perhaps the author meant to write "although" or "even though" or "despite the fact that" or "notwithstanding the fact that"?  It is a concession clause of some kind.

A. The use of standard phantoms is less reliable than the patient method in evaluating the radiation risk {even though} it [the use of standard phantoms] uses a phantom  with a more anatomically realistic background.

B. The use of standard phantoms is less reliable than the patient method in evaluating the radiation risk {even when} it [the use of phantoms] employs a phantom  with a more anatomically realistic background.

To what is the anatomically realistic background of the phantom being compared and judged to be the more realistic of the two? Earlier phantoms with less realistic backgrounds?

Comment: +1 I think you've made the only sense of this that can be found in it.

Comment: Another possibility: "*even when* the phantom's background is made more anatomically realistic."

Comment: From a non-native speaker's point of view, I think the writer dropped *it is*, i.e. "However it is not as reliable in evaluating the radiation risk as is the patient method, nevertheless (it is) employing a phantom with a more anatomically realistic background." So I agree with your interpretation A.

Comment: @Damkerng T. The passage becomes more opaque the more I look at it.  The problem begins with the unclear antecedent for "it" and everything  goes downhill from there.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be nothing out of the ordinary in the usage of "as".

"not as reliable. . . as is the patient method ".  This simply means "not as reliable as the patient method".  The "as" is repeated simply because it got interrupted by "in evaluating the radiation risk". One could eliminate this gap, and the duplicated "as", by inverting thus:

- {In/for}  evaluating the radiation risk, this [method] is not as reliable as the patient method. . . "

The usage of "however" and "nevertheless" (and "employing") is more problematic.  In the existing phrasing, I would replace "however" with "although", change "employing" to "it employs", and leave out the "nevertheless" thus:

- **Although** it is not as reliable. . . method, **it employs**. . .

putting these two fixes together, we get:

- Although, in [terms of] evaluating the radiation risk, this method is not as reliable as the patient method, it does [,nevetheless] employ a phantom with a more anatomically correct background."

Hopefully, this is easier to parse for translation.